# Access google+ user profile photo

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

I am trying to get the user's g+ profile photo. In javascript, i set my data-scope as follows:

```
data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.image"
```

However, the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.image" is an invalid scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login for details.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need `userinfo.profile` -- `plus.login` includes permission to fetch all public info from the user's profile, including their picture.  Simply replacing `userinfo.image` should do the trick.

All the scopes for Google+ are documented here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

Answer (score 0):

follow the [link](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list#try-it)

Use Resource  image.url you will get your answer